# IR Phototransistor Timer

Tags: timer, arduino, velocity

So im using two IR phototransistors paired with an infrared LED to calculate velocity by timing the time between when the first transistor is signaled and the second is signaled. The code works except for the part with the IR transistors. My original code used buttons as a tester just to see if the code worked but now I'm ready to move onto the actual IR receivers. My problem is the while loop that waits for the first transistor to be triggered is not repeatedly checking if the boolean logic is true, it only checks it once before moving onto the next bit of code or doing the while loop.

Heres the code in question

```
int IR1 = 0
int IR2 = 1
val = analogRead(IR1);
val2 = analogRead(IR2);
high = val > 330;
low = val < 330;
high2 = val2 > 330;
low2 = val2 < 330;
while(val == low) {} // waiting for button to be pushed

//begin Timer
//Display on LCD
lcd.clear();
lcd.print("Timing"); //print on LCD
startTime = millis(); //define startTime for calculation



while(val2 == high){} //wait until second button is pressed
// it went low - capture time
endTime = millis(); //define elapsedTime
elapsedTime = endTime - startTime; //deyfine elapsedTime for velocit
//velocity calculation
velocity = distance/(elapsedTime/1000);
```

I know the code is messy, but look at the first while loop because I can't figure out why it's not working

Comment: 2. in your first loop you should update the value of `low` and `val`, whereas in your second loop you should update the value of `high2` and `val2`, because if you don't you get stuck in an *infinite loop*.
3. in your second loop you use the condition `val2 == high`, however `high` refers to the reading from the first sensor, not the second. This should be fixed. 
4. For better accuracy, updating `startTime` should be the very first thing you do after exiting the first loop, rather than wasting time printing stuff on the `lcd`.

Comment: I assume that you had remove some code. Please, post all of it; including var declaration, setup and loop function.

Comment: *Repost after delete: fixed minor error.* 1. It seems to me that there is an issue with analogRead() returning an int in the interval [0, 1023] and low holding values in the interval [0, 1] only. The condition (val == low) would be true if and only if the value read by the photoresistor is equal to exactly *1*, since *low* would be *true/1* and *val* would be *1*, and this  seems to be the wrong semantics wrt. the given context.